# .on("close") running even if user not closed

Tags: node.js, stream, client

So I have a script that needs to run a script when a user closes or disconnects from the stream.

The issue I am having is the following:

1) The below scripts seems to run as soon as they connect to the page.

```
 res.on("close", function() {

     console.log(ip+" client closed")

     var update = {'$set':{
      "endtime":Date.now()
     }},
    options = { upsert: true};

    Listeners.update(userData, update, options, function(error, result) {
      if (!error) {

      }
      else{
       console.log(error);
      }
  });
```

1a) It runs again when a user closes the page (that is correct)

So how do I make sure it ONLY runs when a user disconnects?

And is there a feature for when a user connects? I was hoping like .on("open") - But that did not work for me.

res comes from

```
router.get('/:stationname', (req, res) => {
```

**So in basic forms this is what I need:**

a) when a user enters the page it checks the DB and saves their UUID

b) when a user leaves (closes the page) it updates it with the time that the user exits.

Comment: Please show more code context.  What is `res` and where does it come from?

Comment: @jfriend00 res comes from the router -  router.get('/:stationname', (req, res) => {

Comment: I think you're confused about how this works.  When a user goes to a specific URL in the browser, the browser sends a GET request to the target server.  That opens a TCP connection to the server and then it sends an HTTP command over that TCP connection.  When the server receives that command, it sends the requested content to the browser and the browser is then done with that connection to the server.  There is no tie at all between the lifetime of that connection and how long the user is on that specific page in the browser.

Comment: Now things get a little more complicated with more advanced versions of HTTP that attempt to keep connections alive and/or multiplex multiple request over the same connection.  But again, the lifetime of the connection is not connected to how long the user stays on that page.

Comment: I'd suggest you ask a question about what you're really trying to accomplish.  The only reliable way I know of to track when a user leaves a page is using a webSocket connection between browser and server and the browser will automatically close that webSocket when the page closes (whether it's being replaced by a new page, tab closed or browser closed).

Comment: @jfriend00 see above